# Cloudkit , Unrecognized Selector

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cloudkit

[CKRecord stringForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17412ece0'

I am getting the above error, and not sure what I need to do to correct it.  I am running a query to return CKAssets into a collection view to show pictures.  I want two text fields to match up, and when they do for the image associated to populate the view.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
    @IBOutlet var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
let reuseIdentifier = "MyCell"

var matchedSelfie = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let database = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
    let data = CKRecord(recordType: "theUsers")
    let text1 = data.valueForKey("text1")
    let text2 = data.valueForKey("text2")
    var predicate = NSPredicate(value: text1 === text2)
    let myQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "theUsers", predicate: predicate)

    var mySelfie = matchedSelfie

    publicDB.performQuery(myQuery, inZoneWithID: nil) {
        results, error in
        if error != nil {
            println(error)

        } else {
            for record in results{
                if let aselfie = record.stringForKey("selfie") { //Optional binding
                    mySelfie.append(aselfie) //Append to string array

                    mySelfie.append(aselfie)
                    return ()
                }

            }}}

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
    return matchedSelfie.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollectionViewCell
    let image = UIImage(named: matchedSelfie[indexPath.row])
    cell.matchedSelfie.image = image
    // Configure the cell

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it. The key `selfie` doesn't exist.

You have to check if the key really exists. If the key exists, you can try to use `objectForKey`:

```
let aselfie = record.objectForKey("selfie") as String
```

Comment: Ok, got it.  The error was on the previous view.  It wasn't writing the record to the cloud kit.  Thank you.